# Is there a formal definition for "nesting"?

Tags: html, terminology

In HTML, what does nesting mean exactly? Is there a specification which defines the term?

For example, some sources state that merely placing any element in another is nesting:

```
<div>Thee is a span <span>nested</span> in this div</div>
```

Other sources say that they must be elements of the same type:

```
<span>There is a span <span>nested</span> in another span</span>
```

Still other sources suggest that it is nested only if the elements is the only immediate child:

```
<span><span>nested</span></span>
```

Is there a formal definition, or is "nesting" more of a casual term? Is it related to the definition of HTML or the specifications?

Comment: [Allowed nesting of elements in HTML 4 (and XHTML 1.0)](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nesting.html)

Comment: Forget what I said in my answer :|

Comment: @Mat that would make a fine answer

Comment: @Mat, @Pekka - Is that a credible source? Who is Jukka Korpela? Right now my problem is I have many definitions from equally (un)credible sources.

Comment: Jukka is a pretty reliable source, but that document doesn't define 'nesting', it just uses it casually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a casual and context sensitive term.

Generally, "Nested foos" means "Having a foo that is a (not necessarily direct) descendent of another foo". In a context where it isn't one specific thing being nested, it usually just means "inside but at any depth"

Answer (score 2):

The possible nesting of HTML elements can be derived from the specifications.

[Allowed nesting of elements in HTML 4 (and XHTML 1.0)](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nesting.html) has a presentation for those versions based on:

> ... the transitional DTD, in the 1999-12-24 version of the HTML 4.01 Specification.

(Can't find something more recent that is as complete.)

Nesting is simply the way you put elements inside others, in a tree-like structure. See for instance [Nesting HTML tags](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa090407.htm), [Nesting](http://webtips.dan.info/nesting.html), or [Nesting Tables](http://www.hitmill.com/html/tables/nestingtables.html) (more visual example).

There is no restriction to only the same type of tag (like only considering nesting as placing `div` in another `div`). It's a very generic term as far as I know.

Comment: This tells me what can be nested but does not specify what nesting is.